# How to replace rows starting with a certain character with emptly lines in text file with Linux/Unix?

Tags: linux, unix, text

I'm using Ubuntu and have a large text file where certain rows start with `<` character what I'd like to replace each of these to an empty row. So from this:

```
eeeeee
<
<
aaaa
bbbb
cccc
<
dddddd
<
ff
```

I want this:

```
eeee

aaaa
bbbb
cccc

dddddd

ff
```

(In case of multiple consecutive `<` rows only one empty rows is needed ideally)

How to perform this in command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Perl one-liner should do what you're asking for:

```perl
perl -ne 'if (/^</) {print "\n" if !$f; $f=1} else {$f=0; print}' tmp.txt
```

Here it is in action:

```sh
# cat tmp.txt
eeeeee
<
<
aaaa
bbbb
cccc
<
dddddd
<
ff
# perl -ne 'if (/^</) {print "\n" if !$f; $f=1} else {$f=0; print}' tmp.txt
eeeeee

aaaa
bbbb
cccc

dddddd

ff
```

Commented code:

```perl
# Found a line starting with '<'
if (/^</) {
    # Print a blank line if $f is false
    print "\n" if !$f;
    # Set $f to true so subsequent lines starting with '<' are ignored
    $f=1;
} else {
    # Not a line starting with '<'; reset $f to false
    $f=0;
    # Print the current line
    print;
}
```

Comment: or: `perl -ne '$f=s/^<$//; print if !$f || !$b; $b = $f'`

Comment: @WilliamPursell I mean, if you wanna golf... `perl -pe '$f=/^</?$_=$f?"":$/:0'`

Comment: Very Nice!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You could use sed. In this case the command would look something like:
`sed '/</c\\' file.txt`
This would find a line with a '<' character at the beginning, and replace the line with nothing. It would not however replace multiple empty rows with a single row.